# Multiple RFID tags reading collision

Tags: collision, rfid, reader

Consider passive rfid tags for this question:

When reading multiple rfid tags by the reader, do the multiple rfid tags transmit at the same frequency? If yes then there must be collisions?
How does the reader deal with this problem (if it exists)?

Thanks alot 
ALi Tariq

Comment: Yes, there will be collisions. In many RFID systems, the reader will perform some form of anti-collision sequence. But how is that question related to programming within the scope of Stackoverflow? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and yes there are collisions. Those are handled by the protocol layer. In the RAIN RFID/EPC Gen2 protocol this is for example handled by using a Slotted Aloha mechanism, where the reader divides the available time in slots, and each tag is using one (randomly chosen) slot. Still, collisions occur, but the reader keeps retrying until all tags have been read. This is efficient enough for most use cases.